# Refer to wasb files from oozie command line

Tags: oozie, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to debug an error I'm getting while using Oozie on HDInsight and have found a tip suggesting issuing:

`oozie validate workflow.xml`

from the command-line might help. Unfortunately I don't know how to reference workflow.xml if that file is stored on Azure storage (wasb). I've tried the following:

```
oozie validate wasb://container@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/folder/workflow.xml
oozie validate /folder/workflow.xml
oozie validate folder/workflow.xml
```

but they all fail with "Error: File does not exists"

How do I refer to a wasb file from the Hadoop command-line?

Thanks

JT

Answer (score 0):

We can't able to validate workflow from blob storage. we can validate our workflow from our local drive.

```
For eg :

oozie validate c:\ooziesample\workflow.xml

result : valid workflow
```

it works for me.